# In AngularJs , how does the parent directive call the function which is defined in its child directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call the function in child directive , instead of using the `$scope.$broadcast` to notify the child directive that something happens. 
The outer directive will call the different functions in different child directive at different time.

Comment: you should use isolated scope in directives. `scope:{name: '&'}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use controllers in directive for this.
For example: in link function of child directive, you can save what you want in parent controller, and call then when you want.

Sample

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('parent', function() {
    return {
      controller: function() {
        var parent = this;
        parent.childs = [];
        parent.click = function() {
          parent.childs.forEach(function(child) {
            child.addOne();
          });
        }
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
  })
  .directive('child', function() {
    return {
      require: ['child', '^parent'],
      template: '<div>Child value: {{vm.val}} <input type="button" ng-click="vm.addOne()" value="add one" /></div>',
      controller: function() {
        var child = this;
        child.addOne = function() {
          child.val += 1;
        }
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrls) {
        var childCtrl = ctrls[0],
          parentCtrl = ctrls[1];

        parentCtrl.childs.push(childCtrl);
        childCtrl.val = +attrs.child;

      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div parent>
    <input type="button" ng-click="vm.click()" value="add one to all" />
    <div child="1"></div>
    <div child="2"></div>
    <div child="3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We will need to create an empty object in parent directive scope and pass it to the child directive as a parameter.

While receiving it in child directive – we can inject a method to it

```
app.directive('childDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {

        objectToInject: '=',
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/myTemplate.html',

        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            var killwatch = $scope.$watch('objectToInject', function (value) {
                if(value){
                $scope.Obj = value;
                    /*Injecting the Method*/
                    $scope.Obj.invoke = function(){
                        //Do something
                    }
                    killwatch();
                }    
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And use the object to call the child directive function from parent.